# is_copy_constructible_v<const void*[N]> yields true on GCC since c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits

As mentioned in title:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
  using Ptr = const void*;
  using Arr = Ptr[3];

  // gcc:   passed since c++20
  // clang: failed
  static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Arr>);

}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/enKre9fxr

Have something changed in c++20 that results in this behavior?

I also found [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95153) was marked invalid because

> This is behaving as specified.
>
> ```
> const void* const a[10];
> const void* const b[10](a);
> ```
>
> is valid code in C++20; it initializes `b[0]` with `&a[0]` converted to a `const void*`, and the rest of `b` with null pointers.
>
> The `void*` case is
>
> ```
> void* const a[10];
> void* const b[10](a);
> ```
>
> which is invalid because `&a[0]` is a `void* const*`; converting that to `void*` is not allowed because it casts away constness.

Then I tried this https://godbolt.org/z/zvTr4orvd. However GCC failed to compile `b(a)`. `b{a}` is okey but I think that it's not a copy-construction but a list-initialization. Am I wrong?

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
  using Ptr = const void*;
  using Arr = Ptr[3];

  // gcc:   failed in c++17 but passed in c++20 
  // clang: failed in c++17 and c++20
  static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible_v<Arr>);

  Arr a = {"a", "b", "c"};

  // gcc & clang error: array initializer must be a brace-enclosed initializer list
  // Arr b = a;
  // Arr b(a);
  
  // gcc & clang ok: equivalent to `c = {&a[0]}`
  Arr c{a};

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    std::printf("%p %p\n", a[i], c[i]);
  std::printf("%p\n", (void*)&a[0]);
}
```

Comment: Clang doesn't implement parenthesized aggregate initialization yet, which this change is part of.

Comment: @user17732522 ok, GCC-10 compiles `Arr b(a);` but GCC-11 doesn't. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/Gq4qYnETf it is gcc specific bug.

Comment: @MarekR The behavior of is_copy_constructible is likely not a bug, as metioned [parenthesized aggregate initialization](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html) was adopted in c++20. And it have been implemented from GCC-10. But the part of `Arr b(a);` failed to compile on GCC-11 seems to be a bug.

Comment: Although I doubt that is it even ok to make this special array type as "copy-constructible" with this "non-copying" behavior.

Comment: @VainMan no this is not that. Take a look on that: https://godbolt.org/z/89r4xfEze Note MSVC not gcc fails into this trap, but still `is_copy_constructible_v` works for gcc. C-array must remain not copyable. Your case is special since array contains `void*`.

Comment: @MarekR I'd prefer that is a bug of msvc.  I agree that `is_copy_constructible_v == false` for other array types but except `const void*[N]`.  Because `Arr b(const_cast<const Arr&>(a));` is well-formed. See how [is_copy_constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_constructible) and [is_constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible) is defined.